# Confirmation on a function satisfying specific conditions(Power Series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I had a question, find a function that satisfies the following conditions and I have to use Power series. F is the function.

1) Domain is all reals,
2) $F''(x) = cos(x^2)$,
3) $F'(0) = 3$,
4) $F(0) = 4$,

Basically I used the Taylor series of cosx. So I had $F''(X) = cos(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(x^2)^{2n}}{2n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n}}{2n!}$
I integrated and got $F'(x) = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)(2n!)}) + C$ and since $F'(0) = 3, C = 3$
So, $F'(x) = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)(2n!)}) + 3$
I integrated again and got $F(x) = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)(4n+1)(2n!)}) + 3x + D$ and since $F(0) = 4, D = 4$
So, $F(x) = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)(4n+1)(2n!)}) + 3x + 4$

My question really is, is this correct? Is that how I integrate that series and add the constants C,D? Do those constants still appear when integrating series because that it what usually happens when I integrate any polynomial.

Comment: Everything looks correct.

Comment: (Taking up characters) Thanks!!